# Is it possible to customize an Ubuntu or Debian live system while keeping the secure boot (microsoft keys) compatibility?

Tags: linux, iso-image, livecd, secure-boot

I would like to create a customized live system of either ubuntu or debian while keeping it compatible with the microsoft secure-boot keys, allowing computers to boot this live-system without fiddling with their secure-boot.

Is that possible ? Is there a tool allowing me to do that ?

Comment: You can install all the software you want on both Linux and Windows with or without Secure Boot. What customization do you have in mind?

Comment: I want to pre-install packages from ubuntu and get an iso that I can flash on usb keys to share. I don't want users to have to install such packages after the boot, because they might not have access to Internet.